# How to check a text variable length in makefile?

Tags: makefile

As the title suggests, need to check the length of a text variable in a Make file script

Comment: Can you specify which encoding? If its only ASCII, then [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) has the `explode` function which converts strings into a list of single characters, which you can count with the builtin `words`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything built in, but

```
# XXX BROKEN - see below
len := $(shell printf '%s' '$(VARIABLE)' | wc -c)
```

should roughly do what you want.

This will fail if there are literal single quotes in the value, though. They can be escaped but doing that correctly is tedious and pesky.  Maybe try

```
len := $(shell printf '%s' '$(subst ','"'"',$(VARIABLE))' | wc -c)
```

but I'm not sure I have covered all possible bases.

Maybe also notice the difference between `wc -c` (bytes) and `wc -m` (characters). They yield the same result for plain ASCII, but different results for other Unicode strings (perhaps also depending on your system encoding).